# Getting Backtrace of LLVM Bitcode/IR

Tags: llvm

I am trying to write a program that embeds the LLVM interpreter tool, `lli`. However, I need to be able to get a function backtrace if the IR being run crashes. (I do not mean a backtrace of the interpreter itself, I mean a backtrace through functions in the IR it is running.) Is there any way to do this?